# D3.js tree layout without duplicates

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, duplicates

I have the following json string:

```
{  
  "name":1000,
  "children":[  
  {  
     "name":2000,
     "children":[  

     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":3000,
     "children":[  
        {  
           "name":6000,
           "children":[  
              {  
                 "name":8000,
                 "children":[  

                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {  
           "name":7000,
           "children":[  

           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":4000,
     "children":[  
        {  
           "name":5000,
           "children":[  

           ]
        },
        {  
           "name":5000,
           "children":[  

           ]
        },
        {  
           "name":7000,
           "children":[  

           ]
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

The tree is created successfully using d3, however as it works currently, the node 7000 appears as a child of both 3000 and 4000. What I want to achieve is a single node 7000, with 2 links connecting it to 3000 and 4000 respectively. How can this be done please?

```
// Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

 // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
            return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
        });
```

Should you require further code please do let me know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If a node is a child of two other nodes, it is not a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), by definition. Without trying, I'd therefore assume that the `tree` hierarchy and layout won't process this the way you want them to.

The [Multiple Parent Nodes](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/6afc2ecb05b191359862) example layouts acyclic graph data first as a tree and afterwards adds cyclic edges, in a merely visual way; look for "multiParent" in the longish sample code.

You can do the same here: clone the data, remove duplicates like "7000", and feed this to the tree layout. When drawing, traverse the original data and draw the cyclic edges as well. This may give you quite untidy layouts however, since the layouter doesn't know about all edges and hence cannot optimize node positions such that it minimizes crossing edges.